# Caffe::net reshape

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, deep-dream

I am trying to implement `deepdream` in `C++` in `caffe`(I want to run it in android). `googlenet` requires input of shape `224*224*3`. In the ipython notebook of `deepdream` it shows `src.reshape(1,3,h,w)`. Does this mean that only input blob is reshaped or it is propagated through the network? I tried calling the `net.Reshape()` in `C++` and it resulted in:

```
F0307 01:27:24.529654 31857 inner_product_layer.cpp:64] Check failed: K_ == new_K 
(1024 vs. 319488) Input size incompatible with inner product parameters.
```

Shouldn't the network be reshaped too? If not what is the implication of just reshaping input blob? I am new to deep learning. So forgive me if it seems trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the shape of the input requires reshaping of the entire net. Alas, there are some layer types that do not like to be reshaped. Specifically, "InnerProduct" layer: the number of trainable parameters of an inner product layer depends on the **exact** input shape and the output shape. Therefore a net with an "InnerProduct" layer cannot be reshaped.

You can use methods described in the ["net surgery"](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) example to convert the inner product layers to equivalent convolutional layers (that can be reshaped).

Comment: Should I just propagate reshape to the relevent layers? In `googlenet` only last layer is inner product layer and for the purpose of deepdream I need go through some inceptions layers only.

Comment: I saw the source code of `Net<Dtype>::Reshape()` and it just loops through all the layers. For the purpose of deepdream I only forward to specific layer and backward from that layer. So it seems reasonable to me. Can you elaborate why not?

Comment: @lnman you cannot reshape part of the net, because changing the input shape affects **all** the net. If there are layers you are not going to use, simply remove them: no point leaving them and not reshaping them.